# Array to collection access with arrows?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

If I build a collection from an array:

```
$collection = collect(['name' => 'john', 'age' => '20']);
```

How can I access it like you access models, e.g.

```
$collection->name; //john
```

I'm having to use `$collection['name']`.

Is there a way to access it with arrows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `get()` method:

```
$value = $collection->get('name');
```

Full details at
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-get.

Answer (score 7):

use can used like that also

> convert array to object

```
$collection = (object) collect(['name' => 'john', 'age' => '20'])->all();

$collection->name;
```

Comment: suddenly we need to use all()? previously i didnt do that